# Magento 2 - Change order status when Credit memo created

Tags: magento2, orders, order-status, creditmemo

Below code to create credit memo programmatically

```
public __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory $creditmemoFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\CreditmemoService $creditmemoService,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($data);
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->creditmemoFactory = $creditmemoFactory;
    $this->creditmemoService = $creditmemoService;
    $this->invoice = $invoice; 
}

public function refundCode()
{
    $order = $this->order;
    $order->load(10);

    $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        $invoiceincrementid = $invoice->getIncrementId();
    }

    $invoiceobj = $this->invoice->loadByIncrementId($invoiceincrementid);
    $creditmemo = $this->creditmemoFactory->createByOrder($order);

    // Don't set invoice if you want to do offline refund
    $creditmemo->setInvoice($invoiceobj);

    $this->creditmemoService->refund($creditmemo); 
}
```

Here the function `refund` located at path `vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Service\CreditmemoService.php` does the work, but I could not figure out how it sets the Order Status to `Closed`?

When a credit memo is created, it changes order status to `Closed`. How do I change it to `Canceled`?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by,

```
sales_order_creditmemo_save_after
```

observer, it will trigger once a credit memo has been created. In this observer you can check with order status label

```
if ($order->getStatusLabel() == 'Closed')
```

then you can change it to 'Canceled'.

Answer (score 0):

Try, adding following code

```
$order->setState(Order::STATE_CLOSED)->setStatus($order->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus(Order::STATE_CLOSED));
$order->save();
```

after `$this->creditmemoService->refund($creditmemo);`

This will change the order state and status or the order for which you are generating a credit memo.

Comment: Th question is, when a credit memo is created, it says, `We refunded %amount online` and it has order status 'Closed'. Here I want to change the order status to `Canceled` instead of `Closed`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy to set the status to cancel use Order::STATE_CANCELED